# how to remove .html from URL. application is hosted on amazon s3 & cloud front

Tags: html, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I tried with remove .html from file extensions and added metadata `content-type: "text/html"`. but I need to do this every time.
i tried with `s3 cp --content-type 'text/html' --metadata-directive 'REPLACE' s3://ttestapp/sample  s3://ttestapp/sample`. I have multiple files. is there any way how to remove it. I am not fully aware of AWS. someone suggested lambda expression but I am not able to. is there any way to do it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can do one thing if you have page like `about-us` then create folder `about-us` and put `index.html` inside it. it will be like about-us->index.html. you URL will be like http://example.com/about-us

Comment: it works but it is duplicate URL's for SEO.

Comment: no it will not be duplicate URL for SEO. I used this website its SEO friendly.